# Android RotationMatrix onSensorChanged y axis show toast at 43 and 45 degrees in OrientationActivity

Tags: android, events, matrix, rotation, sensors

I am trying to show when the device is aligned to 43 and 45 degrees respectively on both sides of the y axis (Positive and Negative) rotation.

I got only so far where when rotated it shows toast Front and Back on the
rotation of the y axis.

Find the relevant code section below:

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        float[] rotationMatrix;

```
    switch (event.sensor.getType())
    {
        case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:
            sensorXLabel.setText(R.string.xAxisLabel);
            sensorXValue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));

            sensorYLabel.setText(R.string.yAxisLabel);
            sensorYValue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));

            sensorZLabel.setText(R.string.zAxisLabel);
            sensorZValue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));

            sensorYLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sensorYValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sensorZLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sensorZValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (selectedSensorId == R.id.gravitySensor)
            {
                if (event.values[2] >= GRAVITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    onFaceUp();
                }
                else if (event.values[2] <= (GRAVITY_THRESHOLD * -1)) 
                {
                    onFaceDown();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                accelerationValues = event.values.clone();
                rotationMatrix = generateRotationMatrix();

                if (rotationMatrix != null)
                {
                    determineOrientation(rotationMatrix);
                }
            }

            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accelerationValues = event.values.clone();
            rotationMatrix = generateRotationMatrix();

            if (rotationMatrix != null)
            {
                determineOrientation(rotationMatrix);
            }
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            magneticValues = event.values.clone();
            rotationMatrix = generateRotationMatrix();

            if (rotationMatrix != null)
            {
                determineOrientation(rotationMatrix);
            }
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:

            rotationMatrix = new float[16];
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix,
                    event.values);
            determineOrientation(rotationMatrix);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
{
    Log.d(TAG,
            String.format("Accuracy for sensor %s = %d",
            sensor.getName(), accuracy));
}

/**
 * Generates a rotation matrix using the member data stored in
 * accelerationValues and magneticValues.
 * 
 * @return The rotation matrix returned from
 * {@link android.hardware.SensorManager#getRotationMatrix(float[], float[], float[], float[])}
 * or <code>null</code> if either <code>accelerationValues</code> or
 * <code>magneticValues</code> is null.
 */
private float[] generateRotationMatrix()
{
    float[] rotationMatrix = null;

    if (accelerationValues != null && magneticValues != null)
    {
        rotationMatrix = new float[16];
        boolean rotationMatrixGenerated;
        rotationMatrixGenerated =
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix,
                null,
                accelerationValues,
                magneticValues);

        if (!rotationMatrixGenerated)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.rotationMatrixGenFailureMessage));

            rotationMatrix = null;
        }
    }

    return rotationMatrix;
}

/**
 * Uses the last read accelerometer and gravity values to determine if the
 * device is face up or face down.
 * 
 * @param rotationMatrix The rotation matrix to use if the orientation 
 * calculation
 */
private void determineOrientation(float[] rotationMatrix)
{
    float[] orientationValues = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationValues);

    double azimuth = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[0]);
    double pitch = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[1]);
    double roll = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[2]);

    sensorXLabel.setText(R.string.azimuthLabel);
    sensorXValue.setText(String.valueOf(azimuth));

    sensorYLabel.setText(R.string.pitchLabel);
    sensorYValue.setText(String.valueOf(pitch));

    sensorZLabel.setText(R.string.rollLabel);
    sensorZValue.setText(String.valueOf(roll));

    sensorYLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sensorYValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sensorZLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sensorZValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (pitch <= 10)
    {   
        if (Math.abs(roll) >= 170)
        {
            onFaceDown();
        }
        else if (Math.abs(roll) <= 10)
        {
            onFaceUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: I need to make adjustments at this section of the code. But I don't know how.

Comment: I can get on positive rotation toast to confirm FaceDown()

Comment: I can get on positive rotation toast to confirm FaceDown(),this would be on the y axis positive rotation. But can not get toast in the other direction FaceUp witch would would be negative rotation. So as it stands two thirds of my question has been answered,as the changes need to made on Sensor Change Event. It seems that the problem may be with the units being used. I am using 0-180 positive and visa versa for the negative component on the same y axis.  Therefore I will close this question as answered by myself and pursue a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The changes need to made on Sensor Change Event. It seems that the problem may be with the units being used. Can only toast on positive Rotation.